# Arduino Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'

Tags: c++, arduino

This is really giving me hard time; this simple logic. I will explain how things are going and what I am trying to achieve at this point.

I have an ESP8266 module programed to subscribe to a topic "switches" on a server running Mosquitto MQTT Server.

From any device having MQTT Client, I am able to publish a message to this topic (switches) and send this message through serial using the callback function below.

```
    void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) { 

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    }
      Serial.println();
    }
```

On the Arduino side I am trying to process whatever is coming through the serial port and turn on/off digital pins on the Arduino.

At this point on the Arduino, I have the following simple piece of code that receives bytes and store it in a variable "Recieved_Bytes" and then I am trying to convert those bytes to characters using another variable "Recieved_Message" of type char.

```
void loop(){

  if(esp8266.available()){ // check if the esp is sending a message 

      int Recieved_Bytes = esp8266.read(); //Byte Data
      char Recieved_Message = Serial.write(Recieved_Bytes); // char data;
      GetNumber(Recieved_Message);

   }
```

Everything is fine by far, however when I try to pass this "Recieved_Message" to a function that should return the integer value of what is being sent.

```
const char * Names[] = {"SwitchOne", "SwitchTwo", "SwitchThree", "SwitchFour", "SwitchThirteen"};
const int Numbers[] = {1,2,3,4,13};

int GetNumber(char *name) {
   for (int i=0; i < sizeof Names / sizeof Names[0]; i++) {
       if (strcmp(name, Names[i]) == 0)
            return Numbers[i];
   }
   return -1;  // No match found
}
```

I receive an error - below.

```
PIO_ESP_Control:6: error: initializing argument 1 of 'int GetNumber(char*)' [-fpermissive]
invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

NOTE: Assuming that I will be sending a message "SwitchOne" for example

```
mosquitto_pub -t switches -m "SwitchOne"
```

The question is, what is it that I am doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In your `loop` function, `Received_Message` should be a `char*`. I honestly don't know what `GetNumber` does, but it seems to expect a `char*` as a parameter.

Comment: `char Recieved_Message = Serial.write(Recieved_Bytes);` Are you sure that's what `Serial.write` returns?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz you're right

char Recieved_Bytes = esp8266.read();
Serial.print(Recieved_Bytes);

outputs "SwitchOne" as well

Comment: The thing is that if I used 'GetNumber("SwitchOne");' this works fine and returns "1". Same goes for the rest of the "defined" keywords. SwitchTwo return "2"....etc

Comment: esp8266.read(); return the ASCII code representation for each character. It returns something like "8311910511699104841041051141161011011101310"

Comment: @user2119344 you store the return value of `esp8266.read()` in an `int`, therefore it cannot be something like you say

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is because the method GetNumber is expecting char*, and Received_Message is a just a char. It works when you call GetNumber("SwitchOne"); because "SwitchOne" is an array of characters.

However, I do not think that is the only issue. It seems like in your code you want Recieved_Message to be one of the strings stored in Names, but according to [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) it is just storing the number of bytes written by Serial.write(Recieved_Bytes);

Comment: Okay, so what could be the alternative of Serial.write(Recieved_Bytes) to store the message as an array of character so that I can send it to GetNumber() function ?

Comment: Without knowing exactly how the data returned by esp8622.read() is formatted I can't say for sure. It sounds like it might already be returning an array of characters though, or at least bytes that are formatted the same way. If it is the former calling GetNumber(esp8622.read()) instead of the 3 lines currently within that if statement might work, if it is the latter a simple typecast might do it.

Comment: below is the output of  Serial.print(esp8266.read());

-1-111610410411410111010

Comment: I tried 
'int val = GetNumber((char*)esp8266.read());
 Serial.print(val);'

I got 

'-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1'

Comment: Where is esp8266.read() implemented? Are you importing a library for it? The documentation of that would be helpful. Googling it seems like esp8622.read() returns one character for each call, which means it should call it in a loop to populate an array of chars, and then call GetNumber with that array. Just based on the code samples you have shown here I really don't know what is going on and how you are getting those results. How much do you know about arrays and pointers in C++, and the relationship between them? It seems like some reading on that would help you understand what is going on.